# In Crafter CMS 2.5 Documentation what does Classes in Classes > groovy mean?

Tags: groovy, content-management-system, crafter-cms

In Crafter CMS 2.5 Documentation what does Classes in `Classes > groovy` mean?

> You might notice that we're importing a utils.DateUtils class. This
>   class is not part of Crafter CMS, but instead it is a Groovy class
>   specific to the site. To be able to use this class, you should place
>   it under Classes > groovy > utils and name it DateUtils.groovy, where
>   everything after the groovy directory is part of the class' package.
>   It's recommended for all Groovy classes to follow this convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now know what Classes refer to. It is a folder along side scripts, site, static-assets folder in work area. I wanted to determine this location since I would like to add a custom groovy class. I have added it in this folder: /data/repo/wem-projects/{SITE_NAME}/{SITE_NAME}/work-area/classes/groovy/{PACKAGE_NAME}